# What does "it" refer to?

Tags: pronouns

The passage below comes from Word Smart.

> In grammar, the antecedent of a pronoun is the person, place, or thing
>   to which ***it*** refers. In the previous sentence, the antecedent of ***it*** is
>   antecedent.

When I read the first sentence I thought ***it*** refers to a pronoun.
(Am I right?)
Then the next sentence says 'the antecedent of ***it*** is antecedent'.
Which means the writer thinks ***it*** refers to antecedent.
In that case my assumption about the reference of **it** is wrong.
When a book says something which doesn't accord to my thought, I know I am more wrong than right.
But I want to double check.

Comment: You're right, the writer is wrong. *Pronoun* is the antecedent of *it*; *antecedent* is the antecedent of *which*.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The subject if the sentence ("it") is pronoun. The next sentence you have quoted examines a construct which you have not included in your question. The writer has referred to a sentence which came before the part you quoted.